# select attribute of object according what the user input?

Tags: java, class

How can I access to attributes of object according to the user input?

for example my class is

```
class A{
  public String a;
  public String b;

  //constructor
  A(){
  a="first";
  b="second"; 
}

}
```

and the main program is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  A a=new A();

  Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
  String x=in.next(); // the input it will be "a";
  String y= a.x;
  System.out.println(y);

  x=in.next(); // the input it will be "b";
  y= a.x;
  System.out.println(y);
}
```

Comment: what exactly on what input?

Comment: I mean the input is x;

Comment: And what you want on that input?

Comment: actually the program more complex than this but I try to make the question ease

Comment: Please post the whole thing

Comment: Ok I add the input to my post

Comment: Please explain your motivation. Although there are (complicated) ways of doing what you want, the question is what problem you are trying to solve by doing this, and then we may offer a more reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, you have just to test what's the input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  A a=new A();

  Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
  String x=in.next(); 
  if(x.equals("a")){  // the input is "a";
    String y= a.a;
    System.out.println(y);
  }
  else if(x.equals("b")){ // the input is "b";
    String y= a.b;
    System.out.println(y);
  }
  else System.out.println("Input a or b please !!!");
}
```

If you write `a.x` the compiler will fetch for `x` as a variable of your class `A` and not the input value.

Answer (score -1):

You need [java reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html)

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

class A{
   public String a;
   public String b;

   //constructor
   A(){
      a="first";
      b="second"; 
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      A a=new A();
      Class c = A.class;

      Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
      String x=in.next(); // the input it will be "a";

      Field f = c.getField(x);
      String y = (String) f.get(a);

      System.out.println(y);

      x=in.next(); // the input it will be "b";

      f = c.getField(x);
      y = (String) f.get(a);

      System.out.println(y);
  }
}
```